# Regex to extract the ip address from URL

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone guide me on writing regularexp that I would use in my java code for extracting just the ip from 
`http://10.22.14.152/something/api`

expected result: 10.22.14.152

Comment: This is an XY problem.  The proper way to get the host from a URL is not with a regular expression, but with `new URI(string).getHost()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[use the structure](https://regex101.com/r/cH9uD1/1) of the URL to fashion very simple regular expression:

```
 http://(.*?)/
```

Comment: Might want to put an optional `s?` after `http` and make the trailing slash optional as well.

Answer (score 5):

Just to show a different way to do this, (though sweaver2112's answer is much better)...

You know the format will be in the form of (http:)//(ipaddress)/(directory)/(directory)... You can split around the `/` and grab the 3 element in the array to get the IP...

```
String url = "http://10.22.14.152/something/api";
String[] splitUp = url.split("/");
String ipAddress = splitUp[2];
```

Comment: Why would sweaver's answer be better I actually like yours more. RegEx's are resource-intensive. Often times, string operations such as split or substring are a better way to go - if you don't need the expressiveness of RegEx.

Comment: @BramVanroy RegEx is resource intensive, yes, but for such a small issue, his is easier to read and the bottom line isn't noticeable to the end user. I think my solution helps moreso as you can see exactly what is happening, compared to using a RegEx, but I think in this case, RegEx actually is the better solution... It's an opinion, of course :)

Comment: I finally used java.net.URL to extract the ip address https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html